# E32 LoRa module interoperability with other modem

Tags: lora

I am trying to use the Adafruit modem as a sender, and the E32 as a receiver.
I tried every combination of the air data rate, nothing works. there isn't much else I can configure in the E32.  Below a snapshot of the configuration.

```
HEAD : 11000000 192 C0
 
AddH : 1
AddL : 0
Chan : 15 -> 915MHz
 
SpeedParityBit     : 0 -> 8N1 (Default)
SpeedUARTDatte  : 111 -> 115200bps
SpeedAirDataRate   : 111 -> 19.2kbps
OptionTrans        : 0 -> Transparent transmission (default)
OptionPullup       : 0 -> TXD, RXD, AUX are open-collectors
OptionWakeup       : 100 -> 1250ms
OptionFEC          : 1 -> Turn on Forward Error Correction Switch (Default)
OptionPower        : 1 -> 17dBm
```

Start listening!

The Adafruit configuration has different parameters so it is very hard to compare:

```
Bandwidth =7 (125K)
Spread Factor=7 
Coding Rate=1 
Programmed Preamble=4
```

Any idea how to match the two? The packets I am sending are broadcast packets (address 0);

BTW - I am using the E32 just because it has an SMA connector, if anyone knows about a module that I can use that is more interoperable and has an SMA connector please this will be a huge help as well.

Comment: Hi there! Can you edit into your question the model of this Adafruit modem, and a link to the datasheet as well? Thanks!